# The domain name is resolving to our service but has not been added to a user account

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I am getting this message in my website.I am using facebook and twitter applications in this page.I am not able to figure it out....The canvas URL for facebook application and callback url for twitter are correct.

> Domain name not found in any user account.
>   The domain name is resolving to our service but has not been added to a user account. If you are the owner of this domain name, you may log in and add the domain name to your user account.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The message looks pretty clear to me. What part of it is unclear? It's pretty certainly coming from your hosting company. What URLs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell your hosting service that you want it to host the domain. Just changing the name server entries in the domain registrar isn't enough, you also have to go create an account for it at the hosting service. Log onto your hosting service control panel and look for something like "Add-on domain", "Create acount", etc. There you can specify the domain name to use.